# How should I serve static HTML in Next.js app router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, app-router

I have a few static HTML docs that I want to serve with `__dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in a component in Next.js app router.

1. Where should I put the documents? These are server components, and putting them in `/public` didn't seem to work.
2. How should I render them type-safely?

Comment: It's working where they in the public folder. How are you trying to access them?